# Creating an array and combining keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can amend how items are pushed into a jQuery array? This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
   var sub_updated = [];
    $('.current-sub-items').each(function() {
        $(this).find('.prod-select').each(function() {
            if($(this).parent().css('display') != 'none'){
                var s_main_prod = $(this).val();
                sub_updated.push({
                    product:s_main_prod,
                });
            }
        });
        $(this).find('.var-select').each(function() {
            if($(this).parent().css('display') != 'none'){
                var s_var_prod = $(this).val();
                sub_updated.push({
                    variation:s_var_prod,
                });
            }
        });
    });
    
    console.log(sub_updated);
```

This outputs:

```
0: {product: "201"}
1: {variation: "202"}
2: {product: "192"}
3: {variation: "194"}
4: {product: "965"}
```

How can I output in the following instead?

```
0: {product: "201", variation: "202"}
1: {product: "192", variation: "194"}
2: {product: "965"}
```

Line 2 doesn't have a variation.

Comment: This is a JavaScript, not jQuery, question.

Comment: Logically it sounds like in your second `.each()` you want to check if the element already exists in the array and, if so, add your `variation` property to that existing element.

Comment: In order to better answer this, please supply your HTML so we can avoid some guess work on the mapping here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
var sub_updated = [];
$('.current-sub-items').each(function() {
    var obj = {};
    $(this).find('.prod-select').each(function() {
        if($(this).parent().css('display') != 'none'){
            var s_main_prod = $(this).val();
             if (s_main_prod ){
             obj['product']=s_main_prod
             }
        }
    });
    $(this).find('.var-select').each(function() {
        if($(this).parent().css('display') != 'none'){
            var s_var_prod = $(this).val();
             if (s_var_prod ){
             obj['variation']=s_var_prod
             }
        }
    });
    sub_updated.push(obj);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out a guesswork limb here

- Assume parent `'.current-sub-items'` contains both
- Filter those visible parents by that class
- Get the associated "variation" from that relationship
- Pull those two associated values and push to the array

```js
var sub_updated = [];
$('.current-sub-items').filter(':visible').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.prod-select').each(function() {
    let variation = $(this).closest('.current-sub-items').find('.var-select').val();
    sub_updated.push({
      "product": $(this).val(),
      "variation": variation
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```